# Is it possible to render a shadow in three.js without it having to be cast from an object

Tags: three.js

I am making a horror game and want to make a shadow move on a wall but I want it to appear as if it originated from no particular object. Is this possible and if so how do I implement this?

I have the feeling that dynamic textures will probably be the way to go but I am hoping there is some way using the three.js shadow map

Comment: It's of course possible with the idea being that the object casting the shadow (has to be one) is only visible to the shadow camera and not the regular camera. How to achieve this and is it even possible out of the box i'm not sure. Both Object3D and Camera have a `.layer` property which can be used to render things selectively.

Comment: Iterate through all the objects other than the shadow casting one and `object.layers.enable(2)` which will set them to the second layer. `yourMain.camera.layers.set(2)` to set your camera to render only the second layer. Pray that the shadow camera by default will render layer 1 which all the objects including the shadow casting one should belong to.

Comment: @DevonJarvis If your object currently casts a shadow, try making the object invisible by adding `object.material.colorWrite = false; object.material.depthWrite = false;`

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. @WestLangley, doesn't the depth test need to be on to render shadows from the object?

Comment: @DevonJarvis Did you try what I suggested before asking?

Comment: @WestLangley I hadn't, I have now, the `object.material.colorWrite=false;` was enough. Using `object.material.depthWrite = false;` didn't seem to change anything. If you post this as an answer below I'll upvote it. For interest sake I still want to try the opacity approach mentioned below. If possible I would still like clarification on what the depthWriter does if its not used in the depth test. I assumed this would be similar to turning off the depth mask in WebGL or later versions of OpenGL (I haven't tried rendering shadows without objects in either of those two platforms)

Answer (score 3):

You want a scene object to cast a shadow but be invisible.

First make sure your object will cast a proper shadow, then make the object invisible by adding:

```
object.material.colorWrite = false;
object.material.depthWrite = false;
```

The `depthWrite` setting is required if there are other objects in the scene. That property is not considered by the shadow mapping code.

Alternatively, you can try this, instead:

```
object.material.colorWrite = false;
object.material.transparent = true; // only needed if there are other transparent objects
object.renderOrder = Infinity;
```

three.js r.92

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to achieve this. One of them is by going "under the hood" of THREE.js and rendering the `ShadowMap` separately, with the object `visibility = true`, then setting visibility to `false`, then rendering the scene.

A much easier way is by assigning your object's opacity to something really low. Try 0.0001. It'll cast shadows, but be virtually invisible:

```
var ghostGeom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var ghostMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.0001
});
var ghostMesh = new THREE.Mesh(ghostGeom, ghostMat);
ghostMesh.castShadow = true;
```

Alternatively, you can use `AdditiveBlending` on the material, with the color set to pitch black. This will add `0` color to the final render, while still casting shadows:

```
var ghostMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    transparent: true,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I think what you need is a `Projector` which will cast a quad texture onto the ground or the wall.